# Fatal error: Class 'HttpResponse' not found even after pecl_http loaded in php.ini

Tags: php, pecl

I have installed and loaded PECL http extension.

I have added these lines in php.ini:

```
extension=raphf.so
extension=propro.so
extension=http.so
```

And I see the following being added in the output of

```
phpinfo()
```

HTTP Support enabled, Extension Version 2.0.4

libz 1.2.5 1.2.5

libcurl 7.24.0 7.24.0

libevent disabled disabled

But when I try to use the class HttpResponse I am getting the error:

Fatal error: Class 'HttpResponse' not found in RequestHandler.php on line 21

Can anyone please guide to what I have missed.

Comment: there's also a chance of the file containing the class HttpResponse not being included in the file you are using it. Can you post your code as well?

Comment: You are right I am not explicitly including that file in my code. But then I was reading that for php it is not needed to included code like java, since php does that at runtime?

Comment: PHP would not do it automatically. If you are using a framework, it might have an autoloader that does that.

Comment: Then how do I make php to include the HttpResponse class in my code?

Comment: Can you post your code here?

Comment: private static function createAndSendHttpResponse($responseObject) {
        HttpResponse::status($responseObject->code);
        HttpResponse::setContentType('text/json');
        HttpResponse::setData(json_encode($responseObject));
    }

Comment: Looks like you will have to include the file for this to work. Unfortunately, I don't know which http response class you are using, so don't know how to help you. You could may be try searching for the class using file search, and then include it

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. YAY!!

I was installing pecl_http version 2 and testing methods from version 1. Version 2 has a completely different API than version 1. Who would have guessed :)

Answer (score 0):

What about using code that doesn't require the PECL extension?

For example this is something I used to retrieve a result back from a specially designed aspx file:

```
function getLoginToken($dashboardUrl, $dashboardUsername, $dashboardPassword)
{
    $url = "{$dashboardUrl}GetLoginToken.aspx";
    $data = array('dashboardUsername' => $dashboardUsername,
            'dashboardPassword' => $dashboardPassword);
    $options = array(
            'http' => array(
                'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
                'method'  => 'POST',
                'content' => http_build_query($data),
            ),
            );

    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: The only reason I want to go the PECL route (even though it has beea a real pain in the rear) is because I have been reading that it provides faster processing since it is written in C. What are my non-PECL options for http request and response handling in php